# Android how to loop through this json?

Tags: android, arrays, json

How can I **loop** through this kind of **JSON array**?

```
[
  {
    "full_name": "Abc Xyz"
  },
  {
    "full_name": "Def Xyz"
  },
  {
    "full_name": "Nml Xyz"
  },
  {
    "full_name": "Jol Xyz"
  }
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Simply json what you have tried?

Comment: you might want to read about for loops?

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. It doesn't loop through items.
for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){


                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable

                    String name = json.getString("full_name");
}

Comment: @JohnRombh: What do you mean `didn't work` ? getting any runtime Exception or compile time error message?

Comment: It stops on 1st item.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     try {
        JSONArray a = new JSONArray(myjsonString);
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject o = a.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = o.getString("full_name");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Minimum api level is 19 :|

Answer (score 0):

Your jsonString contains array of objects so here is code:

```
try {
        // [] indicates array so top element is array
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
           // {} indicates object so array elements are objects
           JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           String name = jsonObject.getString("full_name");
        }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Updated : Google GSON**

Also try Google's GSON this is excellent library to handle jsons you can serialize and deserialize the json and class objects.
checkout this link: [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: Minimum api level is 19 :|

Comment: JSONArray and JSONObject are added in API 1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);
        String fullName = json.getString("full_name");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```